# c: pointer errors when passing a 2D array into a function and using helper functions

Tags: c, arrays, function

I wrote two functions to:

1) in `getint`, use an array of integers to return an integer (ex: pass `getint` an array with 8 integers, getint would loop through the array and return an associated integer);

2) in `combine`, pass an array `dec[4]` containing 4 integer arrays and return an array of integers. So you would pass it an array containing 4 int arrays, then it would loop through that array and pass each of the 4 arrays into `getint`. It would then store the returned `int` value into the new array of 4 returned integers (`decInt`) and finally return `decInt`.

I'm getting the errors:

- `no matching function for call to getint` for `decInt[i] = getint(dec[i]);`
- `candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'int *' for 1st argument` for `int getint(int dec[8])`

I'm fairly certain it has to do with incorrect pointers, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
int getint(int dec[8]) {
    int decimal = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(dec[i]==1){
            decimal = decimal+1;
        }
        else{
            decimal=decimal+2;
        }
    }
    return decimal;
}

int* combine(int dec[4]){
    int* decInt = 0;
    decInt = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        decInt[i] = getint(dec[i]);
    }
    return decInt;
}
```

Comment: I guess combine consumes a 2d array or like you said array of arrays. Can you post how you call `combine`?

Comment: While the dimension of the (one-dimensional) arrays passed as arguments doesn't matter (since the arguments are passed as a pointer to the first element anyway), the dimension of the argument `dec` to `combine` and `getint` are different. Not to mention that you pass an `int` *value* from `combine` to `getint`, while it expects a pointer.

Comment: What is your compiler telling you about `getint(dec[i])`? It should be screaming about a type mismatch. Did you intend `decInt[i] = getint(dec);`? Note: on iteration with index `4` in `getint`, Undefined Behavior results.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `getint` expects an array, so I'm looping through the 2d array passed into `combine`  (`dec[4]` should be an array of int arrays) and passing `getint` each of the arrays in the 2d array.

Comment: The problem is `for(int i=0;i<8;i++)` when you send in `int dec[4]` from `combine(int dec[4])`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's less of a problem, considering that the OP is passing `dec[i]` to the `getint` function, which is not a pointer but an `int` *value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are missing the idea of passing 2d array this code demonstrates the idea.

Suppose you have an array like this

```
int a[2][8]={ {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88}};
```

Then when you pass it to a function you will do it like this

```
func(2,8,a);

void func(int row, int col, int a[][col]){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
      for(size_t j = 0; j < col; j++)
          // work with a[i][j]
    for(size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
      func2(col,a[i]);

}

void func2(int row, int a[]){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
      // work with a[i]
}
```

In your case, you were supposed to return an 1d int array which will decay into `int*` but you passed an `int`. Compiler for sure threw error/warning for this but you didn't understand. Actually 2d array of int or more correctly array of array of `int` will decay into `int (*)[8]` or pointer to an array of 8 integers. And the 1d array will decay into `int*`.

#### Extending the same idea you will get

```
int a[4][8];
...
...
combine(a);
...

void combine(int dec[][8]){
...
...
    decInt[i] = getint(dec[i]);
}
```

Here you are not specifying the row or column because you have hard-coded the value in the looping inside of it, which is not a good way of writing it. but yes it would work as long as you pass the array with same column dimension.

---

In your case `getInt()` returns an `int` and takes an input a `int*`.

Now you call `getInt()` with the 1d-array of `int`s and then each call's output you store in an array's element. You then return the address of the allocated chunk (where the array elements are stored).

Comment: So for my code above, a would be int a[4][8], passed into `combine`. `combine` would then loop through and pass the 4 arrays of 8 into `getint` to return 4 integers back into the array created in `combine`.

Comment: Yes- I'm trying to return an int, not an array, into each element of `decInt`. Doesn't getint return an int, which I'm putting into `decInt` which should just contain 4 ints?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing only an integer and expecting pointer to an array of 8 integers.
And more over you are allocating memory for 4 integers and looping 8 times in the other function.